# When I upgrade from 10.12 to 10.13 High Sierra - where do incompatible items go?

Tags: macos, upgrade, high-sierra

Does the upgrade from macOS 10.12 Sierra to macOS 10.13 High Sierra remove any extensions, kernel extensions, Applications or settings that are known to be incompatible or disabled?

I looked briefly at `/var/log/install.log` and see there are over 20,000 lines of things that were logged during the migration and it looks like a lot of things were moved to /Volumes/whatever/Recovered Items but that directory is now deleted and cleaned up.

Additionally, there appears to be a runtime check of this: `Sep 10 16:53:56 MacBook osinstallersetupd[514]: Retrieved package com.apple.pkg.CompatibilityUpdate (http://swcdn.apple.com/content/downloads/47/49/031-75970/fhywgjppj47p6n4udnsqtyszmwfwjt78aj/OSX_10_12_IncompatibleAppList.pkg)` package that now has a 404 not found error.

Are there places to look for what was removed from a specific Mac post upgrade if there's not a more comprehensive list of things we can check before an upgrade?

Answer (score 1):

Incompatible items are moved into a folder at the root of the drive when migration or upgrades happen.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201861

> The software is moved to a folder named Incompatible Software, at the top level of your Mac startup disk.